# Pricing Structure of Amazon S3 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud

I'm a newb at this and just want a clear understanding of how price is calculated.

I want to uses s3 cloud storage so that people can upload video, let's say 5 gb per day, we download the video, make changes and upload again for the person to retrieve.

That is 4x upload/download. Would that be 20gb transfer total? AWS on the high cost allows 100gb transfer per month (https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/aws-s3-pricing/). If each day our transfer is 20gb that will add up pretty fast.

Is there a more cost effective way to do cloud storage?

Thanks!

Comment: if you upload/download the content inside an AZ using the service gateway from VPC, the traffic is not counted. And inbound traffic is not counted as well

Comment: This question is not really suitable for SO. Questions on SO should be about programming, and not about service pricing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pricing for Amazon S3 can be found at: [S3 Pricing by Region | Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

The **data transfer costs** incurred would be:

- **Upload from Internet to S3:** Zero
- **Download from S3 to an Amazon EC2 instance in the same region (for processing):** Zero
- **Upload from EC2 to S3 in same region:** Zero
- **Download from Amazon S3 to Internet:** 9c/GB (in USA, but varies elsewhere!)

For a 5GB file, total *data transfer* costs: **5 x 9c = 45c**

There would also be **storage costs** (2.3c/GB per month) and **request pricing** (way under 1c).